# Performance testing Flex applications

Tags: java, apache-flex, performance, jmeter

What's the best method for performance testing Flex applications with a BlazeDS/Java severs backend. We're looking at JMeter but can it be used with the amf the protocol at a more sophisticated level where values in a request can be manipulated?

Answer (score 2):

My Company (UBIK-INGENIERIE) distributes a commercial Flex/AMF Apache JMeter plugin.

You can easily record, variabilize and replay FLEX/AMF based application with standard knowledge of Apache JMeter.

See a tutorial on it:

- [Performance testing Flex applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429841/performance-testing-flex-applications)
- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-flex-with-jmeter-made-easy/
- https://ubikloadpack.com

Answer (score 0):

The "Java AMF Client" API might help you here. It's a Java API for building and sending AMF requests to the server.

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Java+AMF+Client

I've also heard good things about Gomez but I believe it's a pay service and will require some overhead to get up and running.  But if you're looking for a more comprehensive solution, many people in my company have used it on projects with a Java / BlazeDS backend.

http://www.gomez.com/

Comment: Thanks this might be useful for extending JMeter to include AMF support or maybe putting together our own tool.

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same issue. I will definitely look into www.gorillalogic.com for our site.

Another option (which we overlooked) was choosing LiveCycle Data Services ES2 instead of BlazeDS. While BlazeDS met our functional needs, LiveCycle comes with a Load/Stress tool... something that we really could have used.

Here is the comparison chart:
http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/dataservices/compare.html

Comment: Unfortunately Gorilla logic doesn't offer a tool for performance testing Flex apps. Thanks for the info though in the link though.

Answer (score 0):

Try Neoload

http://www.neotys.com/

(haven't checked it yet myself to be honnest, but I will do it soon)

Comment: This looks like a great option if you're happy to fork out the $8K+ for license fees. We may end up going with this option.

Answer (score 0):

Neoload will cover LCDS, BlazeDS, JBoss, WebLogic, WebSphere, PHP, .NET
We chose it as our tool for testing a Flex app after looking at several options.
You can alter the requests and pass in any variables you like.  Very easy to use but it's not free.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried both NeoLoad and LoadRunner. We had more success with LoadRunner. The only problem was that we had to manipulate the LoadRunner configuration of the generators (including the machine we scripted with in vugen) to allow enough memory to handle the massive requests that Flex made. We were able to run far fewer vusers on generators that tests Flex than those that tested http since each vuser used more memory. It was about a 10:1 ratio or fewer.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, there is no perfect solution for amf encode/decode in JMeter.

Something you can try:

1. Find a programmer (good at Java) develop JMeter plugin for amf
   encode/decode, according to our experience, it is not hard and our
   plugin works fine in the following projects. the plugin should be
   able to decode AMF request when you record request by proxy and easy
   to customize the parameters within the request.
2. Use the charles record the amf request, and attach the data package
       in JMeter http sampler. it works when the app is not complex.
3. Use loadrunner or other commercial software if you can afford.

Comment: See http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-flex-with-jmeter-made-easy/

Answer (score -4):

The best answer for automated testing of Flex application is FlexMonkey - www.gorillalogic.com

The tool is open sourced, can be used in CI environments, has over 5,000 users and is supported by Gorilla Logic (Jave, Flex and mobile development consultants).

Check it out and if you would like more information or a demo, let me know.

Chad S.

Gorilla Logic

Comment: Automated functional testing != performance testing

Comment: Nice try Chad. We briefly thought about using some kind of Flex/Air solution but it falls down on achieving concurrency.