# Using JMeter to test a Flex/Spring web app

Tags: spring, apache-flex, web, jmeter, amf

i have a Flex/Spring web project where the client is a flexapp that runs in the browser and the server components(Spring/Hibernate) runs in tomcat.
The compile dcluient files also obviously reside in the tomcat server.
i want to use JMeter to do some performance testing on the application.
i am new to JMeter and don't know how to connect the JMeter with the application.
From what i understand i cant use the http request based test cases as i am using flex.
Any reference will help.

What kind of plugins do i need on the JMeter instance?
How to configure JMeter to be able to call the application via flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a third-party JMeter plugin.

See

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-flex-with-jmeter-made-easy/
- [How to enable amf sampler type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770078/how-to-enable-amf-sampler-type)
- [Performance testing Flex applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429841/performance-testing-flex-applications)